# Having problems with ElasticSearch OOM with plenty of RAM and ulimits to spare

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch, jvm

We have a 4 server ElasticSearch Cluster, each server has a data/client node with a 16GB ES_HEAP_SIZE and a dedicated master-only node with a 4GB ES_HEAP_SIZE.  For 8 total nodes, 4 of which can do data and 4 that are master only.  Each host has 24 cores with hyperthreading turned off, 256GB of RAM and over 1TB of SSD.  We are running ElasticSearch with CentOS 6.x 64-bit via the service method; RPM install from ElasticSearch's YUM repo (service elasticsearch-node# start, etc).

Problem is we are getting OOM errors on both data and master nodes seemingly at random.  They happen about 2 or 3 times a week as is and can't be directly attributed to load.  We want to add 1 more data node and 1 more client only node to each host with a 16GB ES_HEAP_SIZE each, but attempting to add them only causes OOMs to start almost immediately.

These are the errors:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I tried tinkering with ulimit settings in /etc/security/limits:

```
elasticsearch - nofile 65535
elasticsearch - memlock unlimited
```

But that had no effect, still OOM'ed, so it was removed.

I then tried changing MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535 to MAX_OPEN_FILES=262140 in /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch-node#, but it still OOM'ed.

As for our current settings from /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch-node#:

```
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144
```

I have vm.swappiness set to 1 on each of the 4 hosts, in lieu of mlockall being enabled. And vm.max_map_count=262144 set in my sysctl.

I added some debugging to the elasticsearch start script that writes the running ulimit (ulimit -a) to a file:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 2066148
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 2066148
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

But I don't see anything that stands out.

SElinux is enabled but there's nothing in the audit log except for notifications when I login via SSH or sudo.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: a few things to check: a) is overcommit allowed (the JVM reserves lots of virtual memory) b) if not, are there other processes that reserve significant amounts of memory?  c) does the VM map significant amounts of memory outside the managed heap (direct byte buffers/mmaped files)

Answer (score 1):

The error messsage:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

is indicating that your java process has hit the limit on how many threads it can launch.

Now, the question is, *exactly how many threads is your application trying to launch*.  If its in the thousands, than this is probably not what you want.  If its a reasonable number of threads (e.g 100), maybe you hitting this limit because the limit on your machine is set too low?

Read [this](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread) article for more information.

Also, can you include in your question the output of:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

**Edit**:
Here's a test program I wrote for you to see what your process thread limit is.  Run it on your box.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
                    System.out.println("RunnableJob is being run by " + thread.getName() + " (" + thread.getId() + ")");
                    while(true) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100000);
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
               }
            }).start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're leaking threads in your application?  Have you tried connecting to it with JvisualVM to monitor the # of threads?

Comment: It's elasticsearch, not running anything custom.  I used the nodes API and Nagios and now we graph various JVM usages but don't see anything so far that indicates a memory leak.

Comment: It graphs threads too http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-info.html  "threads" : {
          "count" : 53,
          "peak_count" : 73